# How to capture a high quality screeshot in 1920 x 1080?

Tags: display, screen, resolution, screen-capture

I want to make 1920 x 1080 screenshots of the entire screen, but there's no 1920 x 1080 option in the Displays menu.

There's a 1920 x 1080 option on SwitchResX, but when I select that one, the text on the screen becomes slightly blurry. I suppose that happens because that ratio is not supported, therefore the monitor is stretching or compressing the screen. That said, there shouldn't be any blurriness because there's one black strip on top and one on the bottom of the monitor meaning the monitor is adjusting the size so there no need for stretching or compressing.

Anyone know how to get a clear view in 1920 x 1080?

I am using Macbook Pro 2016, macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

I set the resolution to 1280 x 800 in the Displays menu:

[image]

However, when I take a screenshot of the entire screen, the produced image has a resolution of 2560 x 1600.

If I set the resolution to 1920 x 1200 on the Display menu, the produced screenshot will be 3840 x 2400. I also to set the resolution using the SwitchResX app instead of Displays, but I get the same behaviour.

My end goal is to get a screenshot of the entire screen in 1920 x 1080. How can I do that?

P.S. I also need to capture screencast videos using Camtasia in that same resolution, but the same blurriness issue happens with videos.

I am using Mac Pro 2016, macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Can you please specify the requirement to take the screenshot in that specific resolution? You can always resize a screenshot with/without maintaining the aspect ratio.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I need both screenshots and screencasts (using Camtasia) in that particular resolution. However, even when I use Camtasia, the view is not crisp.

Comment: Any of the native as well as scaled resolution won't render in the desired aspect ratio. You can select one of the options from Display System Preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're having problems is that you are currently using "Retina-mode". This means that the systems outputs a high resolution to the display, but makes it "look like" a lower resolution - which is what is stated on your screenshot. I.e. the display might "look like" 1280x800, but the actual resolution is 2560x1600.

The idea is that the system render text at a much higher resolution, but changes the font size to match, so that the output text is at the same physical size as if you had the low resolution, but it is displayed at the higher resolution meaning that it will be sharper, crisper and easier to read.

In order to change the real resolution to 1920x1080, you'll need to use SwitchResX and change the resolution to 1920x1080. However, take care that you choose the option that doesn't say "HiDPI" to the right. This is the name SwitchResX uses for Retina Mode. If you choose 1920x1080 at the bottom of the list where it is stated without HiDPI, you'll get that real solution - and screenshots are then taken with that resolution.

Doing it this way introduces no artificial blurring, stretching or anything of the sort. Text and everything will be rendedered in 1920x1080 without modification. However, the text will not be as "clear" as when you're using Retina-mode - but you cannot expect more with a 1920x1080 resolution.